# How to run Perl program through an ajax GET method?

Tags: ajax, perl, mod-perl

I have an ajax code where i call a Perl script through querysting with GET method.

Ajax code

```
if(ajaxRequest != null)
{
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "dial1.pl" +  queryString , true);
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = handler;
    //console.log(queryObj.fund);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Perl Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Dial Script for asterisk
# date: 25 July 2013

use strict;
use CGI;
use Fcntl;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
my $cgi = new CGI;


my ($request,$agent_id,@agent_details_url,$agent_name,$agent_terminal_id);
        if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "GET")
                {                                               # if we're receiving a GET
                $request = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};                        # the request is passed in the
                }                                               # environment variable
                                                                # QUERY_STRING
                                                                # else ...
        elsif ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")
                {                                       # if receiving a POST request
                                                        # the length of the posted data
                                                        # is passed in CONTENT_LENGTH,
                                                        # and it is read from stdin
                #$request = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
                read(STDIN, $request,$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}) || die "Could not get query\n";
                }

my $context="Test";
my $query_string="$request";

$query_string=~ s/&//;
my @new_query_string = split(/=/,$query_string);

my $phone=$new_query_string[1];

print "<p>alert($phone)</p>";
print $cgi->header();
print $cgi->start_html('Asterisk Caller');
print '<center><p>call</p>';

sysopen( FH,"/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/meeting_user$$.call", O_RDWR|O_EXCL|O_CREAT, 0777); 

#print FH "Channel: GSM/1/xxxxxxxxx\n";
#print FH "Channel: GSM/1/$phone\n";
print FH "Callerid: 4006\n";
print FH "RetryTime: 60\n";
print FH "WaitTime: 30\n";
print FH "Context: $context\n";
print FH "Extension: s\n";
#printf "<p><b>$dest_nmbr<\/b> &uuml;ber <b>$src_nmbr<\/b><\/p>";

close FH;
```

When i run Perl program manually it is working fine on other hand i got an error through ajax(with browser)

```
[Sun Nov 23 11:36:19 2014] -e: print() on closed filehandle FH at /var/www/perl/dial1.pl line 62.
[Sun Nov 23 11:36:19 2014] -e: print() on closed filehandle FH at /var/www/perl/dial1.pl line 64.
[Sun Nov 23 11:36:19 2014] -e: print() on closed filehandle FH at /var/www/perl/dial1.pl line 65.
[Sun Nov 23 11:36:19 2014] -e: print() on closed filehandle FH at /var/www/perl/dial1.pl line 66.
[Sun Nov 23 11:36:19 2014] -e: print() on closed filehandle FH at /var/www/perl/dial1.pl line 67.
[Sun Nov 23 11:36:19 2014] -e: print() on closed filehandle FH at /var/www/perl/dial1.pl line 68.
```

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong and will appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: I'm guessing the user running the web server (`www-data` on debian-based systems) does not have the access required for `/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/meeting_user$$.call`.

Comment: thnx 4 ur reply @Phylogenesis suppose to i use instead of existing   one open FH, ">/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/meeting_user$$.call" or die "<h2>error: $!<\/h2>"; i got an error "Permission denied" in the web page on other hand manually it is working fine.

Comment: Yes, you need to give the user the web server runs as write access to the `/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing` directory.

Comment: @Phylogenesis i have given the web server as write access to folder or file both ( chown apache:apache /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing) but I'm getting same error please suggest me.....basically I'm using perl-mod.

Comment: Could the problem have to do with whether or not meeting_user$$.call already exists?  From [sysopen documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html): _In many systems the O_EXCL flag is available for opening files in exclusive mode. This is not locking: exclusiveness means here that if the file already exists, sysopen() fails._